# Unravel Index numpy - own implementation

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I try to implement `np.unravel_index` and `np.ravel_multi_index` on my own. 
For `np.ravel_multi_index` I could write this short function:

```
def coord2index(coord, shape):
    return np.concatenate((np.asarray(shape[1:])[::-1].cumprod()[::-1],[1])).dot(coord)
```

But I struggle with finding a similar, short (one-liner) function for `np.unravel_index`. Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Just start with a non-one-liner implementation, then see how to make it more concise. But one liners just for the sake of it is not necessarily a good thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def index2coord(index, shape):
    return ((np.expand_dims(index, 1) // np.r_[1, shape[:0:-1]].cumprod()[::-1]) % shape).T

shape = (2, 3, 4)
coord = [[0, 1], [2, 0], [1, 3]]
print(index2coord(coord2index(coord, shape), shape))
# [[0 1]
#  [2 0]
#  [1 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an implementation that is short, and does not use numpy, but currently only works for a single index, not a set of indices like numpy.unravel_index() does.

```
def index2coord(index: int, shape: tuple) -> tuple:

    coords = list()
    
    for dim_size in shape:
        coords.append(index % dim_size)  # remainder
        index //= dim_size  # quotient
    
    return tuple(coords)
```

N.B. I feel that "on my own" implies not using numpy, otherwise if you're allowed to use numpy, why not just call numpy.unravel_index()?